# can you save the ODBC Connect Str in MS Access when connecting to NetSuite2?

Tags: ms-access, odbc, netsuite

I'm trying to pull data using ODBC from NetSuite2 to MSAccess.  I am trying to put the credentials in the "ODBC Connect Str" Properties, but the query gives me the following error.  "Reserved error (-7754); there is no message for this error."  When I run the query without putting my credentials in the ODBC Connect Str, the query runs successfully.  The problem is I want to save the credentials in the string, but it gives the error shown above.  Is this possible?  Has anyone succeeded in doing this using NetSuite2?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I had to open a ticket with Netsuite support. After a couple days they responded with "The fix for this defect has been released to your account". I don't know what the Fix was, but it worked.

The next problem will be that some of the table names are too long for Access ODBC links. Oh well, one bite at a time.